# TailwindCSS: Issue with Project Root Directory when Configuring tailwindcss.config.js

Tags: tailwind-css

Tailwindcss [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration) states that files in the content
section of `tailwind.config.js` are resolved relative to the
"project root" directory.

**My question is, what does "project root" directory refers to?**

- the directory containing `tailwindcss.config.js`?
- the directory containing `package.json`? (a project can have multiple of those)
- the root git directory( directory containing.git )?
- the current working directory of the tailwindcss command?
  That is, the directory where the command is invoked in.
- the directory containing the actual binary of tailwindcss CLI?

**Update**

Okay, if I am not mistaken the working directory of `tailwindcss` is treated as the project root directory.

For example, if your project layout is something like this:

```bash
./my-project
  |_ src 
  |    |_ index.html 
  |_ tailwind.config.js
```

And, `tailwindcss` is invoked from the root of your project like this:

```bash
cd ./myproject 
tailwindcss --config tailwind.config.js [other options]
```

Then, your `tailwind.config.js` should be configured as:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./src/index.html"],
};
```

However, if we switch into the `src` directory and call `tailwindcss`:

```bash
cd ./myproject/src 
tailwindcss --config tailwind.config.js [other options]
```

Then,  `tailwind.config.js` should read something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    content: ["./index.html"],
};
```